# How to enable API Key deployment in AWS Amplify ReactNative Project

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

> amplify status

returning error as

> GraphQL API is configured to use API_KEY authentication, but API Key
> deployment is disabled, don't forget to create one.

I cannot deploy any api changes to console. How to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured IAM user and Keys? IAM > Users > "amplify-xxxx" > Adminstrator Access or specific policies attached?

[image]

Error is from here:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/blob/fad6377bd384862ca4429cb1a83eee90efd62b58/packages/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/src/display-helpful-urls.js